# Can't count all the inversions while implementing mergesort code

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I've been trying to figure out how to get this code to count all inversions, but just can't seem to put my finger on it. To my understanding this code should count all of the inversions, but it fails many test cases, nudges in the right directions, or even the whole fix would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
int countInversion(vector<int>& v, int& inv) {
    if(v.size() > 1) {
        vector<int> left(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2);
        vector<int> right(v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());

        countInversion(left, inv);
        countInversion(right, inv);

        int l = 0; int r = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if(r >= right.size() || (l < left.size() && left[l] < right[r])) {
                v[i] = left[l++];
            } else {
                if(right[r] < left[l]) inv += left.size() - l;
                v[i] = right[r++];  
            } 
        }
    } return inv;
}
```

The code that did work (I found it on the internet) has very low 
readability can someone help me understand it? and more importantly, point to me what my code exactly missed on and if it's possible to rectify my code to count properly? Thank you!

**Code 2:**

```
long long ans = 0;

void mergei(int a[],int i,int j) {
    int ni = ((i+j)/2) + 1, nj = j + 1;
    int s = i;
    int* arr = new int [j - i + 1];
    j = ni;
    int k = 0;

    while(i < ni && j < nj) {
        if(a[i] <= a[j]) {
            arr[k] = a[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k] = a[j++];
            ans += (ni - i);
        } k++;
    }

    for(; i < ni; i++, k++) arr[k] = a[i];
    for(; j < nj; j++, k++) arr[k] = a[j];
    for(k = 0; s < nj; s++, k++) a[s] = arr[k];
    delete [] arr;
}

void m_sort(int a[],int i,int j) {
    if(i < j) {
        m_sort(a, i, (i+j)/2);
        m_sort(a, ((i+j)/2) + 1, j);
        mergei(a, i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `countInversion` returns something. Should you do something with that when you make the recursive call?

Comment: I'm incrementing it in the else case, and since it's referenced, other calls get the updated value and first call gets the accumulated result, that's how I see it anyway, is that not what is happening? Or am I returning the last return, instead of first?

Comment: Do you mean that my if statements don't return something, well I figured that this would do the right thing too as the if ends for all statements after the completion of the for loop

Comment: I just tried using a global variable so I don't have to think about all of that, still did not work

Comment: OK, I apologize, I see what you are attempting to do now. For the minimum test cases I have run with it from the examples at [Count Inversions in an array using Merge Sort?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-cplusplus-program-to-the-count-inversions-in-an-array-using-merge-sort) and [Counting Inversions using Set in C++ STL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-cplusplus-program-to-the-count-inversions-in-an-array-using-merge-sort) your code is providing the correct inversion count -- what cases is it failing on?

Comment: {2, 1, 3, 1, 2} and [link](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/25392/input01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1577263738&Signature=VxHujTrnK31qLT3%2B7z52A7idShc%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) Rest of the cases fail too, but I will have to unlock them, they're on hackerrank. (I am using long instead of int because of bigger values there as well)

Comment: test case format is number of cases, number of elements in a case, the elements, number of elements in case, the elements...

Comment: Yes, remember hackerrank is all about the corner cases. so I wouldn't be surprised if they are providing all `{ 1, 1, 1, 1...}` and an intentional single inversion pair out of `10000` numbers to sort, etc...  With `{2, 1, 3, 1, 2}` you code gives 3 inversions, `{2, 3} {1, 3} & {1, 2}` -- at least by my reading -- is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, but {1, 2} is present twice, and both are to be counted independently as they are on different indices so output should be 4

Comment: OK, that makes sense, you have the `{1, 2}` pair L->R and the `{1, 2}` pair R->R.

Comment: Yes, I do think my code is missing something on the LL or RR but I thought they are all broken down to single elements and compared in the merge step, but I can't figure out where this is happening or how to fix it, the code only counts split inversions, I'm unable to find a fix.

Comment: Looking at your code, your are incrementing `l++` and `r++` in different `if..else` blocks. You seem to be missing the iteration over `r++` with `left[l] < right[r]` that would pick up the `{1, 2}` L->R pair. I am no fan of geeks (any code that `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is just wrong) but [Counting Inversions using Set in C++ STL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions-using-set-in-c-stl/) using the `std::multiset` implementation is a pretty slick way to go. You can replace the `int arr[], int n` parameters with your single `std::vector<int>& arr` and it works well.

Comment: I just use that because it gets me everything, I don't have to bother with adding a particular header for everything, I don't know if it has downsides? I use g4g for reference while preparing, so I did pick it up from that habit from there heh. Also it does mergesort correctly, so I figured it should do this as well. I will look into that implementation too, it's just I was trying to figure out this one as well! Thanks for all the inputs

Comment: It's it's not a "merge-sort", but the `std::multiset` maintains sort order. If you need to sort the original vector as part of the problem, you can just `.clear()` the vector and then use a range-based `for` loop over the multiset and add the integers back in sorted order. If you don't need the sorted results, then the solution without the sort is trivial. [inversion count](https://paste.opensuse.org/18399837)

Comment: You should not be working with copies of the two original arrays. At first you get the caller's data and a copy of it.  Then you split, but must work with views and make sure that when the shuffling occurs, it's in the original arrays.  That's very important

Comment: I meant my code merges correctly, and the set implementation times out

Comment: @MichaëlRoy You mean I should instead use indices and make modifications to original array always? I don't understand how one would implement that, without changing the code completely

Comment: yes.  Just like the code that David C. Rankin was pointing to above (5th comment).  After all, it is a sort.  It does look like this implementation will not survive, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy the next question is in-place mergesort (merge two sorted arrays without extra space), one step ahead heh, but I think I'm gonna skip that for a while, seems a little too hard at this point. Is that kind of thing even worth doing?

Comment: Yes it's worth doing.  And it comes for free.  And without these very costly allocations, which will make your code crawl to a halt when presented with 100k+ elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve it using my code, I was sure some changes to the `if else` block or how I added the inversions would fix it, it just had to, that's the whole point of mergesort, that's why I was adamant about solving it this way, instead of just using another code. The issue was; I was doing `left[l] < right[r]` which doesn't matter for merging if it's left or right, but does for inversions, just had to change it to `left[l] <= right[r]`.

```
long countInversions(vector<int>& arr, long& inv) {
    if(arr.size() > 1) {
        vector<int> left(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + arr.size()/2);
        vector<int> right(arr.begin() + arr.size()/2, arr.end());

        countInversions(left, inv);
        countInversions(right, inv);

        int l = 0; int r = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if(r >= right.size() || (l < left.size() && left[l] <= right[r])) {
                arr[i] = left[l++];
                // inv += r;
            } else {
                arr[i] = right[r++];
                inv += left.size() - l;
            }
        }
    } return inv;
}
```

A slightly better and more readable code would be:

```
long countInversions(vector<int>& v) {
    if(v.size() <= 1) return 0;

    vector<int> left(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2);
    vector<int> right(v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());

    long inv = countInversions(left) + countInversions(right);

    int l = 0, r = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if(r >= right.size() || (l < left.size() && left[l] <= right[r])) {
            v[i] = left[l++];
            // inv += r;
        } else {
            v[i] = right[r++];
            inv += left.size() - l;
        }
    }     
    return inv;
}
```